# Saving data with dynamic input name to database?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Allright, before that i'm a beginner in PHP.
So forgive me for this silly question.

Say that id_user '1' have 2 items, so it will create 2 input form for each item.

These are the input forms:

```
<input value="0" type="text" name="store_<?php echo $id= "I got this value from id.item in database, in this case '5'" ?>" required="required">

<input value="0" type="text" name="take_<?php echo $id= "I got this value from id.item in database, in this case '5'" ?>" required="required"> 

<input value="0" type="text" name="store_<?php echo $id= "I got this value from id.item in database, in this case '6'" ?>" required="required"> 

<input value="0" type="text" name="take_<?php echo $id= "I got this value from id.item in database, in this case '6'" ?>" required="required">
```

**Note : value take_{id} and store_{id} are retrieved from table 'item' coloumn 'id_item' in database.**

The user input these values :

```
*value 'store' for id_item 5 is 3
*value 'take' for id_item 5 is 2
*value 'store' for id_item 6 is 1
*value 'take' for id_item 6 is 1
```

How do i save value 'store' and 'take' from user input to database with their associated id?
Considering 1 user can have multiple item.

This is table item.

```
    ->id_user (referencing id_user from user's table)
    ->id_item # this primary key
    ->Take
    ->Store
```

So the final result will be like this:

```
id_user : 1
id_item : 5
Store : 3
Take : 2
```

And like this

```
id_user : 1
id_item : 6
Store : 1
Take : 1
```

I've been googled all day, and i think regex with pattern 'store_*' and 'take_*' should do it? or there is another way to accomplish this?
Thankyou :)

Comment: Would it not be easier to use an array, e.g.: `<input value="0" type="text" name="store[<?= $id; ?>] ... />` - then you can just `foreach($_POST['store'] as $id => $value) { ... }`

Comment: Would you like to give example please?
@CD001

Answer (score 0):

```
Set You input like this 
<input value="0" type="text" name="store[]" required="required">

<input value="0" type="text" name="take[]" required="required"> 

<input value="0" type="text" name="store[]" required="required"> 

<input value="0" type="text" name="take[]" required="required">

  and get this value on backside like this   
  $postdata=$_POST;   
  $count= $postdata['store'];  
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){   
       echo $postdata['store'][$i];   
       echo $postdata['take'][$i];   
  }   
 die();    
 see your store and take value
```

Comment: well, it seems to be an endless loop.

Comment: Depends on the user. How much user have item. If user have 1 item, then it will create 2 input, one for store new value of item, and another one  for take it.

Answer (score 0):

Say you're generating your HTML `<input ... />` fields from a PHP loop, something like:

```
foreach($dbResult as $item) {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"store[{$item->getId()}]\" />\n"
        . "<input type=\"text\" name=\"take[{$item->getId()}]\" />\n";
}
```

Which should give you a `$_POST` array like this (using the user input values in your example):

```
Array
(
    [store] => Array
        (
            [5] => 3
            [6] => 1
        )

    [take] => Array
        (
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 1
        )

)
```

Where the `store` and `take` array keys are the *item ids*.

You can then use the keys from either array to generate your loop and insert the data into your database (using `PDO` as an example - errors would need handling in a live environment):

```
if(!empty($_POST['store'])) {

    // we can use the keys from just the `store` array
    // as they'll be the same as those in the `take` array
    foreach(array_keys($_POST['store']) as $itemId) {

        $userId = $_SESSION['user_id']; // from the session for example...
        $storeValue = $_POST['store'][$itemId];
        $takeValue = $_POST['take'][$itemId];

        $qry = "INSERT INTO item(item.id_user, item.id_item, item.store, item.take) "
            . "VALUES(:user_id, :item_id, :store_value, :take_value)";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($qry);
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $itemId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':store_value', $storeValue, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':take_value', $takeValue, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After few hours searching finally i found the answer 
I decided to change a bit for the input form.

```
<input type="text" name="<?php this is id_item?>[0]"> // this array [0] will be assign for 'store' section

<input type="text" name="<?php this is id_item?>[1]"> // this array [1] will be assign for 'take' section
```

I also add 1 *input type=hidden* for retrieving id_item

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php this is id_item ?>[2]" value="<?php this is id_item ?>"> //this array [2] will be assign for send 'id_item' value.
```

And loop the content for receive tha data

```
    for($i=0;$i<How much row i have;$i++){
        $store=intval($my_array[$i][0]);
        $take=intval($my_array[$i][1]);
        $amount=$store-$take;
        $id_item=$my_array[$i][2];
        /////////////////////////////////////
        And do insert command to database right here
```

It's not pretty i know, but it will do the job.

Thankyou for answering and comment on my question :)